# Django Rest Framework - How to serialize nested fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a `CustomerSerializer` which uses a reverse foreign key field `images` to return all associated `Image` objects.

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'images')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'customer')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

This is what I get from the response:

```
[
   {
       'id': 1,
       'name': 'John Doe',
       'images': [
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               ...
       ]
   }
   ...
]
```

Question: Instead of just showing `images` as a list of `id`s, how can I show a different property i.e. `name`?

The desired result would be:

```
[
   {
       'id': 1,
       'name': 'John Doe',
       'images': [
               'foo.jpg',
               'bar.jpg',
               'foobar.jpg',
               'lorem.jpg',
               ...
       ]
   }
   ...
]
```

---

My first attempt - I replaced the reverse foreign key `images` with `image_names` from the `SerializerMethodField()` in order to select the field `name`, but I get a `null` value.

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_names = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_image_names(self, obj):
        return obj.images.name

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image_names')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

---

Additional Info

Example models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

class Image(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

Please let me know if anything is unclear and I will update the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make another serializer like below

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('name',)
```

then update your Customerserializer as below

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'images')
```

Method 2:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'images')
    def get_images(self, obj):
        image_names = obj.images.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
        return image_names
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my question to include my `ImageSerializer` (previously omitted for brevity). As for your solution, I have tried this before, but this returns **ALL** `Image` objects from the DB. I want to return only the related `Image` objects for each particular `Customer` instance. Therefore, I would imagine some Reverse Relationship is necessary?

Comment: @SolidCoder images = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) this is additional code that you haven't added please add that

Comment: I just added the additional code and it now returns a list of `Image` objects. Example object returned within the list is `{ "id": 1, "name": "foo.jpg", "customer": 1 }`. How do I get `foo.jpg`?

Comment: @SolidCoder if you want a flat list of names then use the Method 2 of my answer

Comment: Thanks nishant, Method 2 works perfectly. Much appreciated .